# How to set width of a div in percent in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to set the height/width of an element in percent using JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('header').style.width = '50%';
```

If you are using Firebug or the Chrome/Safari Developer tools, execute the above in the console, and you'll see the Stack Overflow header shrink by 50%.

Comment: However, before initializing in this way, the `style.width` property will be null unless there is an inline-style on this element. Use `getComputedStyle()` for all modern browsers, and `currentStyle` for IE5 and below. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050211/get-value-from-css-using-document-getelementbyid-style-height-javascript/8463292#8463292. Also, jQuery is really the best for handling these browser annoyances.

Answer (score 33):

jQuery way -

```
$("#id").width('30%');
```

Answer (score 12):

I always do it like this:

```
$("#id").css("width", "50%");
```

Answer (score 5):

The question is what do you want the div's height/width to be a percent of?

By default, if you assign a percentage value to a height/width it will be relative to it's direct parent dimensions. If the parent doesn't have a defined height, then it won't work.

So simply, remember to set the height of the parent, then a percentage height will work via the css attribute:

```
obj.style.width = '50%';
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is:

```
<div id="myid">Some Content........</div>

document.getElementById('myid').style.width = '50%';
```

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use **[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2)** and it should be better because

> Since jQuery 1.6, these properties can no longer be set with the .attr() method. They do not have corresponding attributes and are only properties.

```
$(elem).prop('width', '100%');
$(elem).prop('height', '100%');
```

Answer (score 0):

testjs2

```
    $(document).ready(function() { 
      $("#form1").validate({ 
        rules: { 
          name: "required", //simple rule, converted to {required:true} 
          email: { //compound rule 
          required: true, 
          email: true 
        }, 
        url: { 
          url: true 
        }, 
        comment: { 
          required: true 
        } 
        }, 
        messages: { 
          comment: "Please enter a comment." 
        } 
      }); 
    }); 

    function()
    {
    var ok=confirm('Click "OK" to go to yahoo, "CANCEL" to go to hotmail')
    if (ok)
    location="http://www.yahoo.com"
    else
    location="http://www.hotmail.com"
    }

    function changeWidth(){
    var e1 = document.getElementById("e1");
    e1.style.width = 400;
} 

  </script> 

  <style type="text/css"> 
    * { font-family: Verdana; font-size: 11px; line-height: 14px; } 
    .submit { margin-left: 125px; margin-top: 10px;} 
    .label { display: block; float: left; width: 120px; text-align: right; margin-right: 5px; } 
    .form-row { padding: 5px 0; clear: both; width: 700px; } 
    .label.error { width: 250px; display: block; float: left; color: red; padding-left: 10px; } 
    .input[type=text], textarea { width: 250px; float: left; } 
    .textarea { height: 50px; } 
  </style> 

  </head> 
  <body> 

    <form id="form1" method="post" action=""> 
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Name *</span><input type="text" name="name" /></div> 
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">E-Mail *</span><input type="text" name="email" /></div> 
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">URL </span><input type="text" name="url" /></div> 
      <div class="form-row"><span class="label">Your comment *</span><textarea name="comment" ></textarea></div> 
      <div class="form-row"><input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></div> 
      <input type="button" value="change width" onclick="changeWidth()"/>
      <div id="e1" style="width:20px;height:20px; background-color:#096"></div>
    </form> 



  </body> 
</html>
```