# get value from css using document.getElementById().style.height javascript

Tags: javascript

Please offer insight into this mystery.

I am trying to get the height value from a div box by

```
var high = document.getElementById("hintdiv").style.height; 
alert(high);
```

I can get this value just fine if the attribute is contained within the div tag, but it returns a blank value if the attribute is defined in the css section.

This is fine, it shows 100px as a value.  The value can be accessed.

```
<div id="hintdiv" style="height:100px; display: none;">
.
.
var high = document.getElementById("hintdiv").style.height; 
    alert(high);
```

This is not fine, it shows an empty alert screen.  The value is practically 0.

```
#hintdiv
{
height:100px
display: none; 
}

<div id="hintdiv">
.
.
var high = document.getElementById("hintdiv").style.height; 
    alert(high);
```

But I have no problem accessing/changing the "display:none" attribute whether it is in the tag or in the css section.  The div box displays correctly by both attribute definition methods (inside the tag or in the css section).

I also tried to access the value by other variations, but no luck

```
document.getElementById("hintdiv").style.height.value  ----> undefined
document.getElementById("hintdiv").height ---->undefined
document.getElementById("hintdiv").height.value  ----> error, no execution
```

Any solution?

TIA.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1098349/reading-non-inline-css-style-info-from-javascript and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048336/cant-access-css-selectors-properties-from-javascript

Comment: See also: http://gist.github.com/369133 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531737/javascript-incapable-of-getting-elements-max-height-via-element-style-maxheight/

Comment: Thanks all, this was certainly unexpected.  I guess I will do inline style for this 1(or 2 elements).

Answer (score 5):

This is because, when you use `document.getElementById("hintdiv").style.height;` you are accessing the `style` attribute of the tag. If the attribute is not there , then you get no values.

Instead you should use [`currentStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535231(v=VS.85).aspx) object in IE and [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) function in the rest of web browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You CSS syntax is wrong, it sould be `height:100px;` rather than `height:100px`. Note the semicolon.

Answer (score -1):

You should consider usign jQuery instead... it will simplify the thing as $('#hintDiv').height() and it will always return the actual width of the div.

Comment: Thanks DevIT, I need to pick up a jquery book.

Comment: Hi epascarello ! Glad I could help... but to leanr jQuery, you dont absolutly need a book, just try the tutorials on jQuery's website: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials